# Is there a safe / standard way to manage unstructured memory in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm building a toy VM that requires a block of memory for storing and accessing data elements of different types and of different sizes.  I've done this by writing a wrapper class around a uint8_t* data block of the needed size.  That class has some template methods to write / read typed data elements to / from arbitrary locations in the memory block, both of which check to make certain the bounds aren't violated.  These methods use memmove in what I hope is a more or less safe manner.  That said, while I am willing to press on in this direction, I've got to believe that other with more expertise have been here before and might be willing to share their wisdom.  In particular:

1) Is there a class in one of the C++ standards (past, present, future) that has been defined to perform a function similar to what I have outlined above?

2) If not, is there a (preferably free as in beer) library out there that does?

3) Short of that, besides bounds checking and the inevitable issue of writing one type to a memory location and reading a different from that location, are there other issues I should be aware of?

**EDIT**

Here's a simplification (i.e. destructor and some other related methods ommitted) of what I'm trying to do; but it captures the essense of it:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

class block
{
private:
    uint8_t *data;
    size_t size;

protected:
    block(const void* src, size_t size)
        : data(new uint8_t[size]), size(size) { ::memmove(data, src, size); }

    void set(const void* src, size_t dst_adr, size_t len)
    {
        assert( (size > dst_adr) && (size >  len) && ( (size - len) > dst_adr) );
        ::memmove(data+dst_adr, src, len);
    }

    void* get(size_t src_adr) const
    {
        assert( size > src_adr );
        return data+src_adr;
    }

public:
    block(size_t size) : data(new uint8_t[size]), size(size) {}

    size_t get_size() const { return this->size; }

    virtual void copy(const block& src, size_t src_adr, size_t dst_adr, size_t len)
    {
        // Bounds check
        assert( (size > dst_adr) && (size >= len) && ( (size - len) >= dst_adr) );
        assert( (src.size > src_adr) && (src.size >= len) && ( (src.size - len) >= src_adr) );
        ::memmove(data+dst_adr, src.data+src_adr, len);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class typed_block : public block
{
public:
    typed_block(const T& val) : block(&val, sizeof(T)) {}

    // Could use reinterpret_cast here instead, per Ben Voigt below
    operator T () const { return *((T*) this->get(0)); }

    typed_block<T>& operator=(const T& val)
    {
        this->set(*val, 0, get_size());
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    block db(512);
    typed_block<long> x(1 << 30);
    typed_block<short> y(0);

    db.copy(x, 0, 15, x.get_size());
    y.copy(db, 17, 0, y.get_size());

    std::cout << "x = " << x << "\ty = " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So, I guess what I'm really getting at, are there class libraries available (either in or out of any C++ standards) that provide essentially this functionality.  I guess what makes me uncomfortable with this is passing "void *" parameters (even as protected members) in the block class, and I'm looking for a safer way to do this in general.

Thanks.

-&&

Comment: You should read up on strict aliasing rules, which essentially dictate that if you read with one type and write with another, it results in undefined behavior (even for cases where it would work).  However, char/unsigned char are an exception, as they are allowed to alias any type.  Thus, the code above should be safe, at least from a C perspective.   Of course, if the class instance you're storing in the block has a pointer to itself, it will become invalid if you don't keep the real object around.  C++ objects don't like being moved around.

Comment: @joey - Since it's a VM, the content will be things like OPCODE's virtual memory locations and integer / float data types. I typically won't by storing complex class structures in there.  Resolving data types will be handled in the program running in the VM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, since you are in C++, it sounds like you are looking for [STL `allocator`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_(C%2B%2B)) and/or [placement `new`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10).

Comment: The placement new has some possibilities... I'll look into it later (it's late here).

Answer (score 1):

There's `reinterpret_cast`, but it requires proper alignment, `memmove` doesn't.

Comment: This will help for one part (see comment in code segment I posted above).

Answer (score 1):

If you allocate an array of [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/variant.html), then you can allow multiple different types at each position; however, the amount of space allocated per element will be equal the maximum for all the possible types. Note though, that if you only use the primitive types and void*, then that doesn't waste that much space.

Comment: The problem with this is that I won't necessarily know until run time what's in the various memory locations... it looks like boost::variant requires that the possible types be specified at compile time.

Comment: @andand, that is correct; however, if you have some universal base class (let's call it Object), then you can achieve what you want using just the primitives and the type Object*.